# Why is \ character being doubled in my @ string?

Tags: c#, string

```
var phone = @"^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$";
```

phone will then equal `^\\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$`

I thought (and the examples I found seem to show) the @ character meant to leave my string how I have it.  Why is it doubling the \ and how do I stop it?

Comment: [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The visual studio debugger will *show* it as if it were doubled, since in C# a \ would precede an escape sequence. Don't worry - your string is unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

It only *looks* like it's doubled in the debug inspectors.

Note that the strings shown in the inspectors *don't* start with `@` - they are showing how you would have to write the string if you were to do it without the `@`. The two forms are equivalent.

If you're really worried about the contents of the string, output it in a console app.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate in another way, the comparison

```
var equal = @"^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$" == "^\\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$"
```

will always be `true`. As would,

```
var equal = @"\" == "\\";
```

If you examine the variables using the Text Visualizer, you will be shown the plain unescaped string, as it was when you declared it [verbatim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).