# Replace // with / at run time

Tags: c#, string, replace, appium

i'm getting // in path i want single /. whenever i'm debugging it i'm getting // at run time. i have also used replace method. but it isn't working. My code is

```
 string inputFile = 
 Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + 
 "\\InputFiles\\" + config.country + ".txt";
  inputFile = inputFile.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# How to maintain the path as in string without replacing double slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182580/c-sharp-how-to-maintain-the-path-as-in-string-without-replacing-double-slash) or [Why is \ character being doubled in my @ string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478255/why-is-character-being-doubled-in-my-string)

Comment: Actually, the more i think about it, the more this question is confusing

Comment: how are you getting forward slashes in a directory path? they are all supposed to be backwards : ` \ `

Comment: What does "isn´t working mean"? Please be more specific on that. Any errors? Exceptions? Unexpected results? Btw.: if you want a single **forward-slash**, you should use that, if you need **back-slash**, use that. You can´t expect `Replace`  to guess which of the both you actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `\\` only in debug mode, because when visualizing the string literal the debugger is re-escaping it for the visualization purposes, however when operating with it, the string literal will contain only a single `\`.