# using a string variable that represents a filepath in c#?

Tags: c#, escaping, filepath

I have a variable called path which is an external input in my program.

e.g. path = "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\public_privatekey.pfx";

I want to turn path into @"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\public_privatekey.pfx" so that the backslashes don't read as escape characters. The external input cannot manually add in double backslashes in the input. i.e. can't type in "C:\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\public_privatekey.pfx". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you add `@` at the start of the literal string, then the backslashes will be treated as normal characters and not escape characters.

Comment: Only a few seconds before your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942390/replace-with-at-run-time. Anyway if the input comes from an external source (not hardcoded in your code), then the backslahes already *are* escaped. So you don´t have anything to do here.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] @DMac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string comes from an external source and is not hard-coded, e.g. you read it from a file, then the string already *is* escaped. You don´t need to do any further escaping. Just try it out:

```
var path = GetThePath();
ConSole.WriteLine(path); // prints C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\public_privatekey.pfx
```

To verify that simply move your mouse over the `path`-variable when debugging:

[image]
If you however typed the string yourself, you need to escape the slash:

```
var path = "C:\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\public_privatekey.pfx";
```

or even simpler by adding the verbatim:

```
var path = @"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\public_privatekey.pfx";
```

Comment: The thing is, the string will be typed by people other than myself. And I'd rather not say "When referencing filepath, type double backslash for every backslash".

Comment: You don´t need to do that. While reading the file *every* backslash within that file is automatically escaped, see my image above.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the text from the textbox to a string type variable, backslashes will automatically be added to escape the special characters as the framework understands that you are assigning the text to a string variable.

In case you want a programmatic implementation, you can simply use a verbatim string by adding an '@' before your string.

```
string foo = textbox1.text;
```

Or

```
string foo = @"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\public_privatekey.pfx";
```

But remember, quotation marks are not escaped with '@' so if you ever need to escape quotation marks ("), do it as follows:

```
string foo = "some text \"some more text\" and something else here";
```

Comment: The `@` in front of `textbox1.text` is meaningless, you can´t escape a string once created using the verbatim. Either it already *is* escaped or not.

Comment: @HimBromBeere you're right, i pointed that out in the first paragraph of my response. As the question implies the need to impose such an implementation, I wrote it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is configuration rather than code.

My solution would be to use a json/xml/yaml file and read the setting from that at run time.